# Error installing C++ Builder XE7 - "Invalid Serial Number"

Tags: installation, c++builder, c++builder-xe7

During the installation, [C++ Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder) XE7 shows the error:

> Invalid Serial Number.

Deleting all files cglm.ini does not help. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think the most probable reason for this was a **reg** or **slip** file in the same folder as the installer.

I moved installer into empty folder and also cleaned temp folder and after this I was able to continue installation.